# If statement (GTR) in batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

My task is to write a batch file which writes numbers from param1 to param2, if param2 is bigger than param1, then numbers will be written from param2 to param1.

The problem with my code is that it runs from param1 to param2 even if param1 is bigger.

```
echo off
if %~2 GTR %~1 (for /l %%B in (%1,1,%2) do echo %%B) else (for /l %%C in (%2,1,%1) do echo %%C)
```

My input is `test.bat 100 1`

My output is numbers from 1 to 100.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if %~2 GTR %~1 (
   for /l %%B in (%1,1,%2) do echo %%B
) else (
   for /l %%C in (%1,-1,%2) do echo %%C
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%~1" gtr "%~2" (set "step=-1") else (set "step=1")
for /l %%a in (%~1 %step% %~2) do echo %%a
```

You only need to adjust the step